# Knockout.js - Multiple ViewModels per page; page-wide functions with different model contexts

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am building a huge page with multiple forms on it that the user will fill out in sequence.

I want to make each section its own model and was planning on having a masterViewModel that imports the subModels.

Each section, however, has Edit & Save buttons that have the same functions:

1. Edit toggles the model into Edit mode
2. Save validates the inputs, saves the data (via ajax), and toggle the state of the model back

The only difference between the sets of buttons is their model context.

I'm having trouble making a page-level save & edit function that can reference different models using the masterViewModel/subViewModels.

Does anyone have any guidance on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had a function on your root view model, then you can call it from anywhere like `click: $root.save`.

When Knockout calls the function it will set the context (this) to the current data and also pass it as the first argument.  So, the first argument will contain your current model and you can process it from there.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/v22gd/

```
var viewModel = {
    one: {
        name: ko.observable("Bob")   
    },
    two: { 
        name: ko.observable("Sue")
    },
    save: function(model) {
        alert(ko.toJSON(model));
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

with markup like:

```
<div data-bind="with: one">
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.save">Save</button>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: two">
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.save">Save</button>
</div>
```